# Empty, available, not taken

Tags: word-usage

If in a restaurant, if no table is available at the moment, will it be okay to say (other than: "Sorry, there's no table available at the moment)

> Sorry, but all the tables are taken at the moment.
>
> Sorry, but no table is empty at the moment.

---

And is a family is looking for a place to sit, another family says:

> I guess a table's available there.
>
> I guess there is a table that's isn't taken there.
>
> I guess there is an empty table there.

---

And about a specific table:

> I guess that table is available.
>
> I guess that table is empty.
>
> I guess that table isn't taken.

What will a native be most likely to use?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about language used in restaurants, or do you want general information about these sorts of constructions? An American English speaker is unlikely to use any of these examples in a restaurant. They might use them in a different context, though.

Comment: @Juhasz I'm asking about the language used in restaurants by both the people working there and the people going to eat there. ( The people working there can talk to the people working there or people can talk to each other...)

Comment: All of these are common, and all are grammatical and natural.  There is no way to say which is "most common", as it would just be personal opinion and personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

For the first section, no one would use the second example (*Sorry, but no table is empty at the moment.*); it just doesn't flow well and negates a negative which makes it choppy. Someone would either use "Sorry, there's no (aren't any) table(s) available at the moment" or "Sorry, but all the tables are taken at the moment." There are also some other phrases that people would use but it's best to use the simplest one.

The most common one which someone would use (from your examples) would probably be "Sorry, but all the tables are taken at the moment."

For the second section, one of the examples is incorrect "I guess there is a table that **'s**   isn't taken there."
(The bold should be voided), but I'm going to assume that it was a typo and pretend that it wasn't there. The phrase which would probably be most commonly used would be "I guess that table's available." (which is an option in another section but still makes sense here) but that doesn't relate to your other examples. Within your examples, the most common one would be "I guess there is an empty table there." It has a simple structure and uses common vocabulary.

For the third section, somebody would most likely use "I guess that table is available." The reasons can be found in the previous paragraph.

Discarding everything above, which phrase someone uses could also depend on the formality of the discussion, someone might use more complex vocabulary  if they are at a fancy restaurant.

Comment: And what about: "I guess that table is empty" Or "I guess that table isn't taken". Do these sound natural as well?  (Third context)

Comment: Peter Henry:"There are also some other phrases that people would use". Can you please give me an example of one such phrase?

Comment: And what about: "I guess there's a table available there." Doesn't this sound natural?

Comment: Although this is a good attempt at an answer, I have to disagree that one or the other of these phrases is "more common".   I don't think we have any objective way to measure this, and even if we did I suspect the results would be within the bounds of statistical error.  I feel the only "correct" answer should be *All are common, all are grammatical, so feel free to use whichever sounds best to you.*

Comment: @Andrew Although I do believe that is true, I tried to give an accurate answer that fit the question. The person who asked wanted to know the most common, and I tried to provide something which answered their question.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish For your first question; they are pretty wordy compared to the other response. For your second question; "We apologize, but there currently isn't an available table." There are PLENTY more, and more than I could list. For your third question; yes, it does.